# Opening the Translator Task Pane in Office 365 Word

Tags: vba, vb.net, ms-word

From either VBA or VSTO VB.Net I want to open the Translator Task Pane. The following code is all that I have found, which is supposed to open a translate pane:

```
Sub OpenTaskPane()
    Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneTranslate).Visible = True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the method does nothing. No errors and no task pane is displayed.

I know Microsoft has made improvements in the machine translation feature of Office 365 and I suspect that the above VBA method has been obsoleted because it might reference an older version of the task pane, but I have not found anything mentioned about it.

I have also been unsuccessful in trying to find all "updated" members of the Task Pane collection. I thought if I could programmatically list the enumeration values of all members and compare the results to what is documented, that I might be able to find new and undocumented members. But, that's not working out either because the object model doesn't appear to provide that functionality for the Task Pane collection.

The specific task pane I want to programmatically open is this one:

[image]

If anyone has a programmatic solution for opening this task pane, I would appreciate learning about it.

Comment: I can't load your picture for comparison, but I just tried that command and it opened the "Research" task pane with the translation section pre-loaded. So it works for me in the desktop version (Word 2013 15.0.5137.1000 32-bit).

Comment: @SmrtGrunt, Microsoft must have messed it up in the current version of Office. I'm running what is the equivalent to Office 2019 64-bit, though packaged as Office 365 desktop.

Comment: How about `Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneResearch).Visible = True`

Comment: Got it. Sorry for the non-helpful response. Although I guess I can confirm that it used to work?

Comment: @AAA, that opens just the Research Pane in Office 2019/365. Good thought though.

Comment: I use same, it opens up the Research pane with the Translate section

Comment: @AAA, what build number is your version of Office? Are you running a 32 or 64-bit version of Office?

Comment: @RichMichaels, 1905(11629.20214), Office 365. 32 bit

Comment: @AAA, I see it now. The translation choice is at the very bottom of the pull-down menu. And how this translator works is not consistent with the other Translator task pane that you can access from the Review tab ... heavy sigh ... so much for intuitive UI & consistency.